How to disable "debugger;" statement in WebStorm or VS Code
Does anyone know how to disable "debugger;" statement in either VS Code or WebStorm?
I'm trying to debug an app, and it is dynamically generating anonymous functions containing "debugger;" statements, making it very hard to actually debug the rest of the app.
The app then uses eval to call the dynamically generated anonymous function.
Is there functionality in either VS Code or WebStorm to tell it to ignore the "debugger" statement?
Or something in node.exe that I can pass as an argument to tell it to ignore the "debugger" statement?

Answer is nope, You can't ignore debugger statement, Instead you can remove the debugger; string from anonymous code before using eval

I can't remove the anonymous code because like I said, it's generated every time. So, removing it works only once, and it's being generated many times.

open the launch.json file in your project
add the following configuration
"skipFiles":
["<node_internals>/", "/node_modules/**"],
"skipBreakpoints": true
use the node debug flags
node --inspect script.js --no-debug-brk
in webStorm:
go to run edit configurations
comment or disable the code
use a custom configuration or proxy that stipd\s out debugger statements

Test you answer before posting, There is no property skipBreakpoints in launch.json and  option --no-debug-brk in node CLI.

you can basically comment the line debugger; fr fr 

Can't comment out.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
